# How can I change variable resistor wiper / arrow size?

Tags: circuitikz

How can I change variable resistor wiper / arrow size? Is it possible? Seems too small (R3)..

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt, varwidth=\maxdimen]{standalone}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,europeaninductors]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{circuitikz}[european, scale=1]
        
        
        
        \draw (0,0) to[R]  node[xshift=30,yshift=-37]{$\frac{R_{1}}{15,75\;K\Omega}$} (0,4);
        
        \draw (0,4) to[american inductor, *-*] node[xshift=-35,yshift=-15]{$\frac{L_{1}}{15,75\;mH}$} (4,4);
        
        \draw (4,4) to[american inductor] node[xshift=32,yshift=35]{$\frac{L_{2}}{7,875\;mH}$} (4,0);
        
        \draw (0,0) to[short, -*] (4,0);
        
        \draw (4,4) to[C] node[xshift=-15,yshift=-20]{$\frac{C_{2}}{15,75\;nF}$} (8,4);
        
        \draw (8,4) to[R]  node[xshift=30,yshift=37]{$\frac{R_{2}}{78,75\;K\Omega}$} (8,0);
        
        \draw (4,0) to[short, -*] (8,0);
        
        \draw (11,0) to[pR, mirror, name=R3]  node[xshift=30,yshift=-50]{$\frac{R_{3}}{13,5\;K\Omega}$} coordinate(tapR) (11,4);
        \draw (R3.wiper) --  ++ (0.2,0)  |- (tapR) to[short, -*] (tapR);
        
        \draw (8,0) -- (11,0);
        
        \draw (11,4) to[short, *-*] (8,4);
        
        \draw (0,4) -- (0,6) to[C] node[xshift=-55,yshift=-15]{$\frac{C_{1}}{31,5\;nF}$} (11,6) -- (11,4);
    
    
        
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your minimal working example? There is only a image. What did you try?

Comment: Perhaps pR has some wiper property?

Comment: I thought european variable resistors used diagonal arrows, not wipers.

Comment: I would use one at the [bottom](https://dnamemory.ru/wp-content/uploads/4/4/2/4420cc20f6ea2eecde65c5aea42ea3c9.jpeg) for variable resistor (not potentiometer), not sure if it's available in circuitikz..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a real **minimal** example:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[european]
    \draw (0,2) to[pR, name=a] ++(3,0) |- (a.wiper);
    \ctikzset{wiper end arrow={Latex[width=4pt]}}
    \draw (0,0) to[pR, name=b] ++(3,0) |- (b.wiper);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You obtain this:

[image]

(Line thickness woes due to the horrible `okular` antialiasing, sorry).

You can use any arrow of the standard `arrows.meta` package of Ti*k*Z; size options are described [here](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#sec-16.3.1).

It's hidden   in the manual under "Resistive components customization" -> "Arrows":

[image]

Comment: Super, thanks for the PGF/TikZ Manual link also :)